# Should I standardize data using sample statistics?

Tags: standardization

Suppose I sample 1,000 $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ observations

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.randn(1000)
```

The sample mean of `x` is

```py
>>> x.mean()
-0.034215203795331606
```

The (biased) sample standard deviation of `x` is

```py
>>> x.std(ddof = 1)
0.9923790554909595
```

Now suppose that I standardize these observations using these sample statistics

```py
>>> y = (x - x.mean()) / x.std(ddof = 1)
```

The sample mean and (biased) sample standard deviation of `y` are

```py
>>> y.mean()
1.5987211554602253e-17
>>> y.std(ddof = 1)
0.9999999999999999
```

However, I feel that this standardization procedure is a bit misleading, since `y` is no longer normally distributed. More formally, if
\begin{align}
X &\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1) \\
\hat{\mu} &= \frac{1}{1000} \sum_{i=1}^{1000} X_i \\
\hat{\sigma} &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{999} \sum_{i=1}^{1000} (X_i - \hat{\mu})^2}
\end{align}
then
$$
Y = \frac{X - \hat{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma}}
$$
My questions are:

1. If $Y$ is not normally distributed, then when is standardizing data using sample statistics appropriate?
2. How *is* $Y$ distributed?
3. Does this standardization procedure using sample statistics have a name?

### Update

I was not precise enough in my original question. Suppose that
$$
X_1,X_2,...,X_{1000} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
are independent and identically distributed, and suppose that
\begin{align}
\hat{\mu} &= \frac{1}{1000} \sum_{i=1}^{1000} X_i \\
\hat{\sigma} &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{999} \sum_{i=1}^{1000} (X_i - \hat{\mu})^2}
\end{align}
If
$$
\forall i \in \{1,2,...,1000\}, Y_i = \frac{X_i - \hat{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma}}
$$
then are
$$
Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_{1000} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{Y},\sigma_{Y})
$$
for some mean $\mu_{Y}$ and standard deviation $\sigma_{Y}$? It seems that the answer is no, since each $Y_i$ is a non-linear function of $X_1,X_2,...,X_{1000}$ via $\hat{\sigma}$. If I am wrong, then what would $\mu_{Y}$ and $\sigma_{Y}$ be?

Comment: $X$ is normally distributed.  It is characterized by two parameters: a location $\mu$ and a scale $\sigma$.  $Y$ represents a changed location ($X-\hat{\mu}$) and changed scale (multiplication by $\hat{\sigma}^{-1}$) for $X$, but $Y$ is still normally distributed if $X$ is normally distributed.

Comment: @krkeane if $Y$ is a non-linear function of $X_1,X_2,...$, which are normally distributed, via $\hat{\sigma}$, then how is $Y$ normally distributed?

Comment: @krkeane I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Only two things happened to $X_i$ to obtain $Y_i$: you changed location: $(X_i - \hat{\mu})$, then you changed scale: $\frac{1}{\hat{\sigma}}$. These are linear transforms of $X_i$ to $Y_i$.  It does not change the distribution family.

Comment: But both $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ are random variables with their own distributions. If I sampled $X_1,X_2,...$ infinitely many times and each time I performed the same transformation, I would not get the same $Y_1,Y_2,...$

Comment: @krkeane "It does not change the distribution family." - It actually does, see my answer. mhdadk has a point there that deserves to be acknowledged.

Comment: I think this question requires some motivating context to be answerable. "Is __ appropriate?" isn't really answerable without know the goals of the procedure. Facts about the particular distribution of $Y$, and whether or not the distribution of $Y$ depends in a linear or nonlinear way on $X$, might or might not be important, depending on what you're trying to do. A lot of the discussion seems to originate in folks arriving at this thread with different ideas of what problem is being solved, which implicitly shapes which solutions are viable.

Comment: @Sycorax thanks for the feedback. Should I completely re-wrote the question? Or is there a better way of editing it such that the answers don't seem irrelevant? I could also delete this one and post a new one.

Comment: I think it's best to make a new question describing what problem you're trying to solve, how standardization fits into solving it, and articulating exactly what your concerns are.

Comment: @Sycorax should I delete this one before posting a new one? Or should I post a new one with a link to this one?

Comment: The software won't let you delete this question because it has 1 answer with positive score. If you feel this provides helpful context, it's perfectly fine to link to it. But the new question should stand on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a [standard normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), than $Y = (X - \mu)/\sigma$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, as normal distribution is of [location-scale family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family).

> However, I feel that this standardization procedure is a bit
> misleading, since `y` is no longer normally distributed.

What *is* `y` in here? You took 1000 *samples* from a normal distribution and calculated the sample mean and sample standard deviation of the samples. In statistics, you treat those 1000 observed values as 1000 i.i.d. normally distributed random variables (*not* as *a* random variable). You transformed the samples. The statistics you used are estimates of the true parameters, so you can think of the result of the operation as *approximation* of what you would observe if you knew the population parameters and transformed the random variables.

The calculated statistics are *numbers*, you used those numbers to do the transformation. You can use any numbers to scale a variable. Subtracting sample mean and dividing by sample standard deviation is called [normalization, standardization, or converting to $z$-scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score). You use the sample statistics here, not the population parameters, because you don't know the population parameters.

Moreover, you usually care about transforming the samples, not the underlying random variables. Standardization is done mostly for numerical reasons, to ease up the computations. Having samples with a non-zero mean and standard deviation other than one, even if the samples were taken from a standard distribution, would not help with the computations. Don't confuse samples and results of the computations with random variables.

Comment: While I appreciate the practical aspect of your answer, I am actually interested more in the last paragraph of your answer than the rest of it. Could you expand on this? I was told that standardization using sample statistics is never a good idea since it modifies the underlying random variable, but I am not sure how to formalize this.

Comment: I've edited my question to explain what I mean.

Comment: @mhdadk but you almost never know the population parameters, so you cannot standardize using them. Btw, I added a numerical example to illustrate the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for the numerical example. It seems that $Y_i$ is indeed non-normal for small sample sizes and approaches normality as the sample size increases, correct?

Comment: @mhdadk yes, but as said above, you don't standardize random variables but samples. I'm removing the example since it's completely misleading.

Comment: wouldn't knowing that the $Y_i$ are no longer normal be important if you are trying to estimate the parameters of a normal distribution using $Y_i$ instead of $X_i$? It would be like trying to estimate the parameters of one distribution given samples from another distribution.

Comment: @mhdadk <strike>indeed non-normal for small sample sizes</strike> - (1) with a small sample, you could not reject the $Y_i$a are from a normal distribution; (2) the size of the sample does not change the distribution generating the sample.

Comment: @Tim by the way, I thought your numerical example was informative. Maybe add it back with a disclaimer?

Comment: @mhdadk it wasn't, because it was showing something that never happens. It was showing what would happen if you calculated the statistics on one sample and applied to another sample.

Comment: @Tim understood. Any ideas on my previous comment?

Comment: @mhdadk you transform $X$ by adding a number and dividing by a number, it's still normal. You are transforming the samples that you observed, not transforming the random variable using the sample statistics.

Comment: @Tim got it, thanks. If I sample $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ then standardize these samples, would this be the same as sampling from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Comment: @mhdadk no it wouldn't. If you sample from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then the mean of the population is 0 and sd of the population is 1, sample means are different. If you sample from other distribution and standardized, then the mean of the sample is 0, and sd of the sample is 1. You're confusing random variables with their realizations.

Comment: @NickCox yep, thanks, muscle memory to add `^2`.

Answer (score 4):

I had to edit this after already having picked up 2 votes because I realised that what I wrote about the conditional distribution isn't correct. In fact this is a surprisingly tricky question.

1. A major reason to standardise is if you have several different variables and want to make their values comparable. If you only have a single variable, I don't really see the point of it. Generally whether standardisation makes sense or not depends on what you do with the (un-)standardised data.

Note in particular that there is no reason to standardise if you want to estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$, because standardisation amounts to removing the information about $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from the data.

2. The fact that $Y$ is not normally distributed is a nice observation. In fact, it's not *i.i.d.* normally distributed.
   "I.i.d." means identically and independently distributed. Independence is violated, because in particular the $Y_i$ have to sum up to zero, meaning that if you know $n-1$ of them, you know exactly what the last one has to be.

The marginals have mean $\mu_Y=0$ and variance $\sigma_Y^2=\frac{n-1}{n}$, however they are not normal, see below. That their mean is zero is easy to check (note that if random variables that are identically distributed sum up to zero, all their expected values must be zero regardless of dependence). The variance can be obtained from a similar argument, realising that $\sum Y_i^2=n-1$.

However, the marginals cannot be normal, because for example, if $n=2$, $Y_1=3$ is impossible because then $Y_2=-3$ because of $\sum Y_i=0$, and $\sum Y_i^2=9\neq 1$, which it need be. This means that the range of values of $Y_i$ is bounded, hence cannot be normal. (In fact, if $n=2$, $Y_i$ can only be $\pm\sqrt{0.5}$; from $n\ge 3$ it should be continuously distributed, but still with bounded range, as too large absolute values would spoil $\sum Y_i^2=n-1$.)

I had earlier claimed that  $Y_i$ is normally distributed *conditionally on* $\hat \mu$ and $\hat\sigma$, but that's not true either, because knowing $\hat \mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ doesn't change the argument above.

Interestingly, if you plot $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$, they will have the same distributional shape as $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, which are i.i.d. normal, just with different mean and sd, so normality will be kept in a certain sense, but I don't know how to make that a formal statement.

3. Many names are in use, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score

Comment: "However in practice what is relevant is that $Y$ is normally distributed *conditionally* on $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$." What does this sentence mean exactly?

Comment: I think you could have been clearer by writing "$Y$ is normally distributed given $X_1,X_2,...,X_{1000}$", since both $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ are functions of $X_1,X_2,...,X_{1000}$.

Comment: I was wrong and have changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Be patient, there's still something wrong.

Comment: Interesting. I appreciate all the explanation I can get. Upvoted for the effort.

Comment: Not sure about this paragraph: "I had earlier claimed that $Y_i$ s normally distributed conditionally on $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$, but that's not true either, because knowing $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ doesn't change the argument above." From what I understood, since $$Y_i = \frac{X_i - \hat{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma}}$$ then if you are given all $X_1,X_2,...,X_{1000}$, $Y_i$ would no longer be random, since the right-hand side of this equation is a constant.

Comment: "Conditionally on $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\sigma$" means that  $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ are given, but *not* all $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127601/discussion-between-mhdadk-and-lewian).

Comment: What is gained by such standardization?  Why use a method that assumes a symmetric distribution?  Why use non-robust statistical quantities to do the standardization?

Comment: @FrankHarrell I used to perform this standardization before I realized that the sample mean and standard deviation are not the same as the population mean and standard deviation. More precisely, after sampling some data, I would compute the sample mean and standard deviation and I would find that they are not exactly equal to the population mean and standard deviation. To fix this, I would perform this kind of standardization to make sure the sample mean and standard deviation match the population mean and...

Comment: ...standard deviation. Of course, I no longer perform this kind of standardization, since I am aware that the sample mean and standard deviation will never be equal to the population mean and standard deviation. However, I was curious to see how this standardization procedure affects the distribution of $Y_i$, and therefore see how it would affect maximum likelihood estimation of the parameters of the distribution from which the $X_i$ were sampled from.

Comment: @Lewian since $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ are functions of $X_1,X_2,...X_{1000}$, how would $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ be given without being given $X_1,X_2,...X_{1000}$?

Comment: @mhdadk you are making the common error of believing that the sample mean and standard deviation are adequate parameters to be used for standardization.   They have problems even if sample estimates are close to population truths.

Comment: @FrankHarrell would you like to expand on this in an answer? Specifically, what problems do the sample and standard deviation have and what better statistics can be used for standardization instead.

Comment: First of all I question the use of standardization.  But if one **must** standardize, just question everything.  Mean and SD are not robust, SD assumes symmetric distributions, and require distributions to be somewhat similar to normal distributions.  There are many quantile-based measures that have fewer problems but require larger sample sizes.

Comment: @mhdadk: "How would $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ be given without being given $X_1,X_2,,\ldots,X_{1000}$?" I'm addressing theoretical questions here and conditional probabilities given $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ but not $X_1,X_2,,\ldots,X_{1000}$ are well defined. Somebody may have told you what $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ are but not the original data. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @FrankHarrell: Not sure why you discuss this in the comments to my answer, because my answer addresses the distributional issue raised by mhdadk (which I think is pretty interesting) without making specific recommendations about how to standardise in practice.